# Loading around 50gb of parquet data to Redshift taking indefinite time to load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am loading around 50 gb of
Parquet data into Dataframe using Glue Etl job and then trying to load into Redshift table which is taking more 6-7 hrs and not even completing.

`datasink=glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame=<data_frame>,
catalog_connection="redshift_connection",
connection_options={
"preactions": pre_actions,
"dbtable": dest_table,
"database": "<redshift_database>",
},
redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
transformation_ctx="datasink",
)

Is there any performance improvement techniques one needs to follow ?

Tried partitioning the data and made significant changes with resource configuration.Using G2.x with 16 workers

Comment: Do you know which step is taking this long?  Is it the Redshift COPY?  If so, how many files / how large are the files in S3?

Comment: Yes above step where it is trying to write to Redshift is taking a longer time …other step before that takes hardly 5 mins….files are there in multiple partition is s3 ….say around 500 partition we have for now …I am trying to load data for around 150 partition just to test the Redshift load …Else I need to load all partition data to Redshif for day .partition is like - date/type/version..Each partition can have 1 files or more depending on the size  ….since I am reading 150 partition together so data size is almost around 10gb

Comment: Moving that much data from S3 to Redshift should be on the order of 1-5min depending on cluster size (or much less for larger clusters).  One way I can see that this could take this long is if you have over 250,000 files to load.  (S3 has an indexing costs.)  Do you have access to the Redshift console and can post the performance information for the COPY command that is being issued?  How many files?  Is it from S3 (vs SSH)? Is it cross region?  So many possibilities and seeing some perf data will narrow things down.

Comment: I checked that before writing data to Redshift , it gets copied to temp directory in s3 , when I checked s3 temp dir ...I noticed that 10 GB parquet is written as 3 TB as csv in tmp dir . And that would be the reason that data copying is slow

Comment: So I tried a different approach where I am saving dataframe to s3 in csv with gzip format and 10 GB of parquet is written as 20GB of csv with gzip in s3 . and running COPY to redhsift command copies fast .........But this time I am getting Redshift CPU utilization as 100% just for COPY command , however it takes only 19 min to copy .....But CPU utilisation should not be 100% ....I have 120 files of csv in gzip format in s3 and each file having size around 200MB

Comment: As you can see when working with very large amounts of data S3 can become a bottleneck.  Too many tiny files and things go very slow.  Too few very large files and no parallelism is achieved also being slow.  Many 1-10GB files is a happy balance for S3.  Parquet should be faster than CSV but it looks like you are not getting enough files to enable parallelism (if I'm reading correctly).

Comment: The high CPU percentage is likely due to auto-sort, compression, and auto-analyze occurring during the COPY.  Of these sorting is the most CPU intensive. If you COPY to an empty table Redshift will automatically sort the incoming data to match the tables sort keys.  see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-load-in-sort-key-order.html  Sorting this much data is a lot of work.

Comment: So what do you suggest to define a proper sort keys for a table.

Comment: Many 1-10GB files is a happy balance for S3. Didnt get this? Can you please explain 
I can’t write the data in Parquet format because my org has some issue with copy command with parquet format and a case is already opened with Aws

Comment: Picking proper sort keys is primarily a function of query patterns on Redshift.  A good place to start would be SORTKEY AUTO if you don't have a good sense of how your queries will make use of the sort key / metadata.  The only downside with this is that Redshift will learn over time what keys are likely best so some resorting of the table may be needed over time.

Comment: If you are asking why S3 wants files of a certain size I can explain.  When moving data from S3 to another cluster (like Redshift) you want to have as many parallel network connections moving the data.  But only a single file can only be moved on one connection.  S3 is a massively parallel cluster but Redshift is only as parallel as the number of slices in the cluster.  If you have 64 slices in your RS cluster then you can have 64 parallel network connections.  So you want at least 64 files to make use of this parallelism.  More is better so that the work per slice can balance out.

Comment: However, on the other side you want to have files that are efficient to move out of S3 and this means that they need to somewhat large.  S3 is an object store (not a file system) and as such each access requires a hashed lookup of where the file is located in the S3 cluster.  This takes time - approximately 5.-.75 sec.  This isn't huge but when you are accessing many many file serially this can add up.  Accessing 1 million 100byte files serially is only moving 100MB of data and the transfer time of this data should only be 8 sec. But the lookup time for all the files is 278 hours!

Comment: There's no reason that you cannot use parquet (or csv) efficiently for loading into Redshift.  You just need to follow best practices for accessing this much data from S3.

Comment: No there is ongoing issue with data loading with parquet we are getting and a case is raised with aws support team